# MoveWindow API in windows 8

Tags: windows, winforms, winapi, windows-8

I need to open an external window from an external exe (eg Notepad) and move & size it to a predefined size & position.

I am trying to use MoveWindow API but is seems it is not working. I am using Windows 8 x64 and VS2012.

Here is my code:

```
    <DllImport("user32.dll")> _
Public Function MoveWindow(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal x As Integer, ByVal y As Integer, ByVal nWidth As Integer, ByVal nHeight As Integer, ByVal bRepaint As Boolean) As Boolean
End Function

Public Sub NoveNotepad()
    Dim ApplicationProcess = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("Notepad.exe")
    ApplicationProcess.WaitForInputIdle()
    Dim ApplicationHandle = ApplicationProcess.MainWindowHandle
    Dim z = MoveWindow(ApplicationHandle, 600, 600, 600, 600, True) ' THIS RETURNS TRUE
End Sub
```

Comment: So you need to do what the documentation tells you to do. When MoveWindow returns false, you find out more information by calling `GetLastError`. In .net you do that by setting SetLastError to True in your DllImport attribute and reading Marshal.GetLastWin32Error. Please show the result of that.

Comment: I'm running Win8.1 on x64 and that code worked fine after adding `Shared` to the API declaration.

Comment: Sorry, but now the Api call returned True.
As regards to the Shared, I'm using it in a module, so no need to use Shared.

Comment: So did it return True and actually work, or return True and **not** work?

Comment: Returned True but still did not work.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using SetWindowPos() instead?  Not sure why MoveWindow() wouldn't work...

```
Private Declare Function SetWindowPos Lib "user32" Alias "SetWindowPos" _
    (ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal hWndInsertAfter As Integer, _
    ByVal x As Integer, ByVal y As Integer, ByVal cx As Integer, ByVal cy As Integer, _
    ByVal wFlags As Integer) As Integer

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim ApplicationProcess = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("Notepad.exe")
    ApplicationProcess.WaitForInputIdle()

    Dim ApplicationHandle = ApplicationProcess.MainWindowHandle
    SetWindowPos(ApplicationHandle, 0, 600, 600, 600, 600, 0)
End Sub
```

Comment: Still no progress. Exactly the same.
SetWindowsPos() returns 1.